# How can I pass variable when render view to script tag in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm using hbs as a template engine along with html.
This is my setting.

```
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.engine('html', hbs.__express);
```

In my route.js

```
router.get('/home', isAuthenticated, function(req, res){
    res.render('home', { 
        user: data something });
});
```

In my home.html I want to use user variable not as a template but to do something

```
<script>
    var user = {{user}}; // It don't recognize user variable
    /* do something about user variable */
</script>
```

Comment: Try `{{@user}}` You're using Handlebars rendering engine, more info on correct syntax can be found here: https://github.com/donpark/hbs#exposing-locals-as-template-data

Comment: @laggingreflex Thank you for your answer. In addition how can I convert that data into String. Now, It is var user = mydata; // It doesn't have a string quotation. I try using mydata.toString() and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9):

Extending **ting-y**'s answer.

If `user` is number or boolean:

```
var user = {{user}};
```

If `user` is a string:

```
var user = "{{user}}";
```

If user is an object or array, convert it into urlencoded JSON string and use:

```
var user = JSON.parse(decodeURI("{{user}}");
```

### Standard approach

I like to you this more clean approach in rendering javascript variables using handlbars

#### json_utils.js

```
function tryParseJSON (jsonString){
    try {
        var o = JSON.parse(jsonString);

        if (o && typeof o === "object") {
            return o;
        }
    }
    catch (e) { }

    return null;
}


module.exports.safeJSONParse =tryParseJSON;

module.exports.encodeJSON =  function(obj) {

    obj = JSON.stringify(obj);

    return encodeURI(obj);
};

module.exports.decodeJSON = function(obj) {

    obj = decodeURI(obj);

    console.log(obj);

    return tryParseJSON(obj);
};
```

#### app.js

```
var express = require("express"),
    jsonUtils = require("./json_utils");
var app = express();

app.get("/",function(req,res) {

          var data = {
                 "name" : "John Doe",
                 "age" : 18,
                 "isAlive" : false,
                 "emergencyContacts" : [999999999,888888888,777777777]
          };

          res.render("home",{ "data" : jsonUtils.encodeJSON(data)});

});
```

#### home.handlebars

```
<script src="/utils_json_client.js"></script>
<script>
        var data = jsonDecode("{{data}}");
        console.log(data);
         // {
         //    "name" : "John Doe",
         //    "age" : 18,
         //    "isAlive" : false,
         //    "emergencyContacts" : [999999999,888888888,777777777]
         //}
<script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try `var user = "{{user}}";`

if you user only contains string

Answer (score 0):

You're using Handlebars rendering engine, the correct syntax would be `{{@user}}` [more info](https://github.com/donpark/hbs#exposing-locals-as-template-data)

Surround them with quotes to cast those values into variables in javascript

```
<script>
    var user = "{{@user}}";
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use like this if your variable is a object. If you just type var={{user}} it will give an error if you type var user='{{user}}' it will be a string.

But if it is an object you must initialize with [].

```
var user = ['{{user}}'];
```